# Basic video editing using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, video, .net-4.8, wmp

I'm building a C# application (Windows Forms and .NetFramework 4.8). I use the Accord.Net framework to record a video in .mp4 format on the computer. After recording, I am using the Windows Media Player control to play the video that was recorded.

```
string applicationFolder = Application.StartupPath;

if (File.Exists(applicationFolder + @"\temp\videoTemp.mp4"))
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = applicationFolder + @"\temp\videoTemp.mp4";
}
```

I need to edit this video by adding a text at the bottom for a specific time. During recording I can add text using the command below before saving the frame in the .mp4 file:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(currentFrame))
{
    //g.DrawString("test"...);
}
```

I thought of doing the same with the video that is played by the Windows Media Player control. For that I looked for some event of the player where I can get a pointer to each new frame of the video playing, but no success.

When creating a Windows Media Player Graphics, the text is reproduced in the video, but only when the application is running, the saved video is not affected.

```
using (Graphics g = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.CreateGraphics())
{
    //g.DrawString("test"...); //it's show only when application is running
}
```

The question: Does Windows Media Player have any feature where I can capture the current frame of the video being played? If not, is there any way to recover a video saved on the computer, edit it frame by frame and then save it by overwriting the old video using C#?

Sorry for my English. Thank you everyone.

Comment: No, Windows Media _PLAYER_ doesn't have any ability to _edit_ media. Editing media, especially video, is much more complicated than you think.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Windows Media Player have any feature where I can capture the current frame of the video being played?

No, it's a player. And even if it did, it certainly can't write the result. Since it's a player and all.

> If not, is there any way to recover a video saved on the computer, edit it frame by frame and then save it by overwriting the old video using C#?

I generally use `ffmpeg` for that, it's not terribly difficult and it has hardware acceleration both for decoding and recoding built-in.